# Directive Inside another directive. Controller can't watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have 2 simple directives...

**the parent directive**:

```
.directive('modal', [function () {
return {
  replace: true,
  scope: {
     /* attributes */
  },
  templateUrl: 'modal.tpl.html',
  transclude: true,
  link: function (scope) {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

**the child directive**

```
.directive('keypad', function () {
'use strict';

return {
  templateUrl: 'keypad.tpl.html',
  scope: {
      value: '=',
  },

  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
    /* code */
  }
};
```

and finally **the controller**:

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.$watch('howMuch', function(){
        console.log('wont work ;-(');
    });
}
```

and my **template** looks like this:

```
<div modal>
    <div keypad class="keypad" value="howMuch"></div>
</div>
```

Any idea why the child directive can't change the howMuch value on the controller?
The same code but WITHOUT the parent directive works PERFECT.

Answer (score 0):

The parent directive has an isolate scope.  You didn't show the scope attributes, but `howMuch` needs to be accessed via a property in your isolated scope in order to update the value in the controller's scope.

Comment: I need something more general... sometimes the modal directive is gonna contain another directives or static content. How can I do that?

Comment: You can certainly do that, but when you isolate your scope, you cut yourself off from the rest of the scope world, unless you expose the in/outs via the isolate scope.  OR, you don't isolate your scope... but more often than not, you want isolated scope